# How to trigger a sub-view rendering on initial route render?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I know this is easy to do in the trivial case, but I have added the ability to change which controller & sub-template are used for a particular `{{outlet}}` sub view, and that has confused me to the point of restoring the basics.

I have a working example on [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/hakefeke/18/edit). Use [this link](http://jsbin.com/hakefeke/18#/activities/new) if you want to jump straight to the screen in question.

The problem arises on the `activites\new` route. I would like the view to start with the text

> *Please select a template to continue editing the activity.*

When it is initially rendered. But to get this text to appear, you have to select one template, then turn the select back to the prompt `- Select Template -`.

These are the relevant object which accomplish the selection change template render action.

```
// NewActivityController extends EditActivityController, so this observable 
// is re-used without being shared
App.EditActivityController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    activityTypeDidChange: function() {
      var selectedType = this.get('activityType');
      console.log("EditActivityController ActivityTypeDidChange: "
        + (selectedType && selectedType.get('key') || 'null'));
      this.send('changeType', selectedType);
    }.observes('model.activityType')
});

// The controller dispatches an event to trigger the action in the route
App.NewActivityRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('edit_activity', {
      controller: 'new_activity'
    });
    // This doesn't work for setting the initial sub-render
    //var type = model.get('activityType');
    //if(type) {
      //this.render("Edit"+type.key, {into: 'index'});
    //} else {
      //this.render("NoActivityType", {into: 'index'});
    //}
  },
  model: function() {
    return App.Activity.create({
      title: "please enter a title",
      subjectCode: "please enter a subject code",
      activityCode: "please enter an activity code",
      activityType: null
    });
  },
  actions: {
    changeType: function(selection) {
      console.log("NewActivityRoute ChangeType called: "
        + (selection && selection.get('key') || 'null'));
      if(selection) {
        this.render("Edit"+selection.get('key'),
                    {outlet: 'edit', into: 'edit_activity'});
      } else {
        this.render("NoActivityType",
                    {outlet: 'edit', into: 'edit_activity'});
      }
    }
  }
});
```

As the comments say, you can't get the model on the initial render. Even uncommenting just the `model.get` line causes the event dispatch between the controller and the route to break.

If you pop open the console, you can see that the `EditActivityController`'s `ActivityTypeDidChange` observer is fired when the model's `activityType` is initialized to `null`. This dispatches the `changeType` event, but it actually bubbles up to the `ApplicationRoute`, so the `NewActivityRoute` can't handle it to render the proper sub-view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had a fundamental misunderstanding of the [`Route.renderTemplate`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) hook. It turns out that you can't just expect the `model` to be defined in the method, you have to specify it as a parameter.

> `renderTemplate` (**controller**, **model**)
> <sub>Defined in [packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js:1148](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/v1.4.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1148)</sub>
>
> A hook you can use to render the template for the current route.
>
> This method is called with the controller for the current route and the `model` supplied by the model hook. By default, it renders the route's template, configured with the `controller` for the route.

Parameters bolded in the function declaration for clarity. Adding the parameters to my `renderTemplate` code hook works exactly as I expected it to in the first place.

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
  this.render('edit_activity', {
    controller: 'new_activity'
  });

  var type = model.get('activityType');
  if(type) {
    this.render("Edit"+type.key,
      {outlet: 'edit', into: 'edit_activity'});
  } else {
    this.render("NoActivityType",
      {outlet: 'edit', into: 'edit_activity'});
  }
}
```